# PHP Ajax Like System

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a like / dislike system for my websites commenting system.

I was working off of this tutorial, http://www.webcodo.net/like-dislike-system-with-jquery-ajax-and-php-youtube-like-design/

Except I have multiple like/dislike buttons on every page, because there's multiple comments people have the ability to like/dislike.

I'm brand new to ajax btw.

Here's the javascript file.

```
$('.like-btn').click(function(){
    $('.dislike-btn').removeClass('dislike-h');    
    $(this).addClass('like-h');
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../outfits/outfit.php",
        data:'act=like&function=true&pageID=' + pageID + '&user=' + email,
        success: function(){
        }
    });
});

$('.dislike-btn').click(function(){
    $('.like-btn').removeClass('like-h');
    $(this).addClass('dislike-h');
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../outfits/outfit.php",
        data:'act=dislike&function=true&pageID=' + pageID + '&user=' + email,
        success: function(){
        }
    });
});
```

This is the "comment row"

```
<div class="row">
                    <h5>Comments</h5>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 columns">
                            <textarea rows="4" class="post-comment" placeholder="You can comment or rate without doing the other" name="comment" maxlength="140"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-10 large-10 columns">
                            <div class="rating">
<input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5">5 stars</label>
<input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4">4 stars</label>
<input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3">3 stars</label>
<input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2">2 stars</label>
<input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1">1 star</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-2 large-2 columns">
                            <input type="submit" name="postComment" class="small button radius login-button right" value="Post">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 columns">
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                        foreach ($commentRows as $commentRow) {
                                try {
                                $pageID = $commentRow['id']; // The ID of the page, the article or the video ...

                                    extract($_POST);

                                    $dislike_sql = 'SELECT * FROM  likes WHERE user = "'.$email.'" and comment_id = "'.$pageID.'" and rate = 2 ';
                                    $stmt = $dbhandle->prepare($dislike_sql);
                                    $stmt->execute();

                                    $dislike_count = $stmt->rowCount();


                                    $like_sql = 'SELECT * FROM  likes WHERE user = "'.$email.'" and comment_id = "'.$pageID.'" and rate = 1 ';

                                    $stmt = $dbhandle->prepare($like_sql);
                                    $stmt->execute();

                                    $like_count = $stmt->rowCount();


                                    if($act == 'like'): //if the user click on "like"
                                    if(($like_count == 0) && ($dislike_count == 0)){

                                        $rate = 1;
                                        $sql = 'INSERT INTO likes (comment_id, user, rate )VALUES(:pageID, :email, :rate)';

                                        //prepare data for insert
                                        $stmt = $dbhandle->prepare($sql);

                                        $stmt->bindValue(":pageID", $pageID);
                                        $stmt->bindValue(":email", $email);
                                        $stmt->bindValue(":rate", $rate);

                                        //Execute
                                        $stmt->execute();
                                    }
                                    if($dislike_count == 1){

                                        $rate = 1;

                                        $sql = 'UPDATE likes SET rate = ? WHERE comment_id = ? and user = ?';

                                        $stmt = $dbhandle->prepare($sql);
                                        $stmt->execute(array($rate, $pageID, $email));
                                    }
                                    endif;

                                    if($act == 'dislike'): //if the user click on "like"
                                    if(($like_count == 0) && ($dislike_count == 0)){

                                        $rate = 2;
                                        $sql = 'INSERT INTO likes (comment_id, user, rate )VALUES("'.$pageID.'", "'.$email.'", "2")';

                                        //prepare data for insert
                                        $stmt = $dbhandle->prepare($sql);

                                        $stmt->bindValue(":pageID", $pageID);
                                        $stmt->bindValue(":email", $email);
                                        $stmt->bindValue(":rate", $rate);

                                        //Execute
                                        $stmt->execute();
                                    }
                                    if($like_count == 1){

                                        $rate = 2;
                                        $sql = 'UPDATE likes SET rate = ? WHERE comment_id = ? and user = ?';

                                        $stmt = $dbhandle->prepare($sql);
                                        $stmt->execute(array($rate, $pageID, $email));
                                    }
                                    endif;
                                }
                                catch (PDOException $e) {
                                    echo $e->getMessage();   
                                }
                                print '<div class="row comment-row" id="gohere">
                                <div class="small-12 columns">
                                    <div class="small-12 columns">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="small-12 large-2 columns text-center">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="small-12 columns">
                                                        <span>' . $commentRow['first-name'] . '</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="small-12 columns">
                                                        <img src="https://a3-images.myspacecdn.com/images03/1/240e42b5d9ce48a78983961e7fcb3c39/300x300.jpg" class="profile-pic-comment" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="small-12 large-10 columns comments">
                                                <div class="small-12 columns comment-text">
                                                    <span>' . $commentRow['text'] . '</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="small-12 large-4 columns right">
                                                    <div class="small-6 columns">
                                                        <div class="like-btn' . $commentRow['id'] . ' ';
                                                        if($like_count == 1){
                                                            echo 'like-h';
                                                        }

                                                        print '">Like</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="small-6 columns">
                                                        <div class="dislike-btn' . $commentRow['id'] . ' ';

                                                        if($dislike_count == 1){
                                                            echo 'dislike-h';
                                                        }
                                                        print '"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>';
                            }
                    ?>
                </div>
```

Right now I can see the counts of the likes / dislikes, which is all zero because the insert and update queries are not working. I put in data manually to see if the count was working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I need to post anymore details/code.

Comment: Any response from the Server?

Comment: As in errors? There are no errors, and I have `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` set. I think I'm just going to start over, and not work from the tutorial. I have a better understanding of ajax now anyway, which is the main reason I was working from that link. I'm sure the problem is simple, because at one point I had the like button functioning, but not the dislike button. But regardless, at this point I'm starting from scratch.

Comment: As in Response. Open the Development Console of your browser, go to Network or similar and see what happens if you click this button. There should appear a post request and inside it should be a response from the server.

Comment: I'll remember this in the future, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

You code try for count() instead using rowCount() function.

```
$CountLikes = count($smpt);
```

I don't think that's the issue. Anyways, since you said you are new to AJAX, have you tried using the like system without AJAX. Not saying, the problem lies in the AJAX, but it will either rule out whether or not your issue is Server-Side or if it's an AJAX issue. Ruling out where the issue is will help you a lot.

If it works successfully without the AJAX, then we can assume that AJAX is not sending the data to the server correctly. You can work from there.